# How to decrease 1 second to a given time

Tags: javascript, php

my output right now is increasing instead of decreasing when I even subtract it
Here I got responsetime.php

```
   <?php
session_start();
require_once 'includes/dbh.php';
$sql='SELECT * FROM acceptedorder;';
$stmt=mysqli_stmt_init($conn);
if(!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt,$sql)){
echo "Eror in statements";
}else{
mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
$result=mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);
while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
    if($row['fname']!=""){
$duration=$row['duration'];
echo $row['duration'];
echo "<br>";
}}
}

$durated=$row['duration'];
$startime=date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
$end_time=date('Y-m-d 
H:i:s',strtotime('+'.$durated.'minutes',strtotime($startime)));
$_SESSION['endtime']=$end_time;
$from_time=date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
$to_time=$_SESSION['endtime'];
$timefirst=strtotime($from_time);
$timesecond=strtotime($to_time);
$differenceinseconds=$timefirst-$timesecond;
echo gmdate('H:i:s', $differenceinseconds);
```

And an index.php which will I display the time

session_start();

```
<script type="text/javascript">
setInterval(function(){
    var xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.open("GET",'responseTime.php',false);
    xmlhttp.send(null);
    document.getElementById('response').innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
},1000);
    </script>
```

Comment: I'm guessing it's because you're doing string - to time - to int and that's causing you issues, is `(int)$timefirst` a value like "1.01"? Could you please dump it out? :)

Comment: I got rid of it still no progress

Comment: first tell us more fully what the intention of the code is. What should be the relationship between "start_time", "endtime" and "durating"? Which variable is supposed to have one second subtracted from it, and when?

Comment: Also, what output are you getting, and what output were you expecting?

Comment: Here i echo out $from time and I get 2019-03-13 11:19:10 and for the $end_time 2019-03-13 11:19:10 and my output now is 10:20:43 the number should be decreasing instead of increasing

Comment: Huh? But those times are identical? Also, that while loop is going to only give you the data from the last returned row of the query result set.

Comment: ops the endtime is supposed to be 1970-01-01 01:00:00 haven't copy it lol. Yes its fine im just trying it for 1 row only

Comment: I get it i should just change $timefirst-$timesecond to $timesecond-$timefirst

Answer (score 1):

Try getting the difference between the two DateTime values and then formatting it into seconds:

```
$differenceInTime = $from_time->diff($to_time);

$differenceInSeconds $differenceInTime->format("%s");
```

Answer (score 1):

I should just change

```
$differenceinseconds = $timefirst - $timesecond;
```

to

```
$differenceinseconds = $timesecond - $timefirst;
```

Answer (score 1):

I would do it with DateTime and DateInterval.

```
$now = new DateTime('now');
$minusOneSecond = $now->sub(new DateInterval('PT1S'));
echo $minusOneSecond->format('d-m-Y H:i:s');
```